# SQL Server query to stack columns vertically for summation, with multiple variables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have several columns that contain multiple variables and their associated values. I want to stack the Variable columns and their associated Value columns for summation.

Each variable (eg ABC) may or may not appear in each column. There are about 200 variables (and their associated values) that may appear in 10 variable/value columns. I have just shown 6 variables in 3 variable/value pairs.

Here are my columns:

```
Variable1   Value1  Variable2   Value2  Variable3   Value3
ABC          1      ABC          9        ABC           6
DEF          2      DEF          8        DEF           5
XYZ          3      XYZ          7        XYZ           4
KLM          4      KLM          6        KLM           3
TUV          5                            TUV           2
                                          GHI           1
```

Here is my desired output:

```
VariableAll  ValueAll
ABC           16
DEF           15
XYZ           14
KLM           13
TUV            7
GHI            1
```

Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 separate selects, one for each columns pair, and `union all` to combine them into single result.

```
declare @t table(Variable1 varchar(50), Value1 int, Variable2 varchar(50), Value2 int, Variable3 varchar(50), Value3 int)
insert into @t(Variable1,   Value1,  Variable2,   Value2,  Variable3,   Value3) values
('ABC',    1, 'ABC',    9, 'ABC', 6),
('DEF',    2, 'DEF',    8, 'DEF', 5),
('XYZ',    3, 'XYZ',    7, 'XYZ', 4),
('KLM',    4, 'KLM',    6, 'KLM', 3),
('TUV',    5,  null, null, 'TUV', 2),
( null, null,  null, null, 'GHI', 1)


;with cte (Variable, [Value]) as (
select Variable1, Value1 from @t where Variable1 is not null
union all
select Variable2, Value2 from @t where Variable2 is not null
union all
select Variable3, Value3 from @t where Variable3 is not null
)
select Variable, SUM([Value]) as Total
from cte
group by Variable
order by Total desc
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought there may be no easier way of doing this. There are hundreds of thousands of records in the dataset I'm working on, and as I mentioned, about 200 variables that are repeated across 10 columns, so defining each in a separate select statement is impossible. I do appreciate your response though.